# C-S-Backspace not working

Tags: key-bindings, terminal-emacs

When using emacs, C-S-Backspace seems to only delete one char and not the whole line.

After reading [Here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Killing-by-Lines.html) I see the text:

> "C-S-backspace (kill-whole-line) kills a whole line including its
>   newline, regardless of the position of point within the line. Note
>   that many text terminals will prevent you from typing the key sequence
>   C-S-backspace."

This might explain my problem, but does not give me a solution.

Checking topics like [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7927/controlmeta-key-is-not-working) gives some explanation to possible Ubuntu based issues, but they seem to be GUI based. I'm using the Awesome window manager with the default configs. I don't see anything bound to those keys.

I'm using Ubuntu with Awesome WM. My terminal is XTerm. I'm using emacs 24.3.1.

Comment: It's probably not because it is bound to something else, it's because this key combination is translated into something else, like `C-backspace` maybe. I rebind it to `C-backspace` anyway since I use `M-DEL` to delete word, so I'm not losing anything.

Comment: Type `C-h k C-S-backspace` to see if you are using `kill-whole-line`, that manual you linked is for latest stable Emacs version: 24.5, not 24.3.

Comment: It looks like when I rebind C-backspace to kill-whole-line it seems to still delete one char to the left. C-h k C-backspace is "It is bound to DEL.".